# How to add CDI support to existing web project in Java EE 6 with Netbeans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I created a new `Java Web/Web Application` Project in Netbeans 8.0.2 using Java EE 6 Web profile and not activating the checkbox `Enable Contexts and Dependency Injection`. Now the project has grown bigger and I want to add CDI support without restarting the project from scratch.

In Eclipse you can do that via `File/Properties/Project Facets` by activating the checkbox CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection).

How can this be done in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no separate capability (or Facet in case of Eclipse)  for CDI.

EDIT : Java EE 6 needs bean.xml to be present in WEB-INF. I believe if you add it explicitly then you will get the support enabled automatically. Any UI to do that is something i am not aware.